# fingerprintJS2 lifecycle bug

Tags: node.js, npm, fingerprintjs2

I've downloaded fingerprintJS2 and I'm trying to run an npm test. I keep getting back an error that I can't see to figure out at all. Please see below. We have PhantomJS and don't know why it's having a lifecycle error. Would love any feedback on this. Thank you in advance!

```
'specs' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! fingerprintjs2@1.8.1 test: `specs/phantomjs.runner.sh specs/spec_runner.html`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the fingerprintjs2@1.8.1 test script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\J\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-08-05T20_37_32_524Z-debug.log
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1
```

Comment: can you post your test script from package json?

Comment: @AritraChakraborty Hey! Where can I find this? The package.json of fingerprintJS2 only contains below. Do you mean the fingerprintJS2 test script package contents? Thank you! {
  "name": "fingerprintjs",
  "version": "0.5.3",
  "main": "fingerprint.js",
     "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.2",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.6.3",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.2.2"
  }
}

Comment: in your working directory there is a file called package.json, in there copy the entire 'scripts' field

Comment: @AritraChakraborty I'm not sure how to post it in comments in the correct format as I did in the initial question :/

Comment: don't post it in the comments. add it in the question. you can edit the question. there is button to do that.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/I6Q6APB   <-Is this the correct location? It feels like I'm doing something wrong.